# Gmail: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Tags: smtp, gmail, go, smtp-auth

This Go program successfully sends email from my home computer, but on a virtual server on DigitalOcean receives the following error:

```
panic: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

Here's the code:

```
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "bjorkbjorksen@gmail.com", "PASSWORD", "smtp.gmail.com")
msg := "Subject: Hello\r\n\r\nWorld!"
e = smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587", auth, "bjorkbjorksen@gmail.com", []string{email}, []byte(msg))
if e != nil { panic(e) }
```

Answer (score 39):

Get to your Gmail account's security settings and set permissions for "**Less secure apps**" to **Enabled**.
Worked for me.

Comment: This is the link you're looking for: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: @MichaelZi What should I do if __Less Secure apps__ must stay __Disabled__?

Comment: it works perfect but is this the best way to do it ??

Answer (score 13):

Derp!  I signed into the account and there was a "Suspicious login attempt" warning message at the top of the page.  After clicking the warning and authorizing the access, everything works.

Answer (score 8):

You need to go here https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

then select Gmail and then select device. then click on Generate. Simply Copy & Paste password which is generated by Google.

Comment: Getting "The setting you are looking for is not available for your account."

Comment: It's look like you did not enable 2nd step verification on. https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification

Answer (score 0):

You need turn on the POP mail and IMAP mail feature in setting of the email you are using to send mail.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

in may case setting SMTPAuth to true fixed it. Of-course you need to set permissions for "Less secure apps" to Enabled.

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;