# Failure sending mail?

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp, smtpclient

I have a problem in this code i am new please help me

**Error is :** `Failure sending mail.`

**Inner Exception is :** `Unable to connect to the remote server.`

Here is my code:

```
    try
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    message.To.Add(emaild_id);
    message.From = new MailAddress(my_email_id);
    message.Subject = "Info";
    message.Body = "something.....";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strFromMail, strPassword);
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Send(message);
    MessageBox.Show("Mail has been sent successfully.");
}
catch (Exception ErrMessage)
{
            MessageBox.Show(ErrMessage.Message, "ASCEND", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
 }
```

Comment: Throw the exception correctly...example :  catch(exception ex){throw ex}

Comment: Change your port to 465

Comment: now i edit the catch block

Comment: i changed the port but again i got same exception

Comment: Change the catch block this catch(exception ex){throw ex} . Then check it.

Comment: check if any antivirus is blocking the sending of mails. Usually anitvirus like mcafee has email scanner that may block.. just turn it off and see..

Comment: I have changed now i get this error **Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed**

Comment: Check the reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect

Comment: If your hosting provider does not allow outbound 587, you may need to use HTTP instead. For example, you might use the Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/ Even locally, you might consider using HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Port number 465 instead of 587

Comment: Which namespace are you using to send an email? System.Web.Mail OR System.Net.Mail?

Comment: System.Net.Mail only using

Comment: Try using System.Web.Mail. I know it is deprecated, but, it may resolve your issue

Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011245/how-can-i-send-emails-through-ssl-smtp-with-the-net-framework/1014876#1014876