# Error while sending email through Office365 using SMTP

Tags: c#

When I am trying to send email using Office365 through SMTP, I got the following exception.

"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."

Comment: have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect

Comment: We need more information to help you, the error message on its own is not enough. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @bman It didn't help. I am already using Port 587. Also tried with Port 25. Neither helped