# How to link existing sendgrid account to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, smtp, umbraco, sendgrid

I just migrated my apps to Azure. Now my app has a sending email feature that uses Sendgrid to send email. But now I want to link this account to Azure as I think I need to link this (existing Sendgrid account) to my Azure Sendgrid Account. But how do I do this? In Azure Sendgrid it only allows me to create a Sendgrid account but there are no option to Add an existing Sendgrid account. How do I do this? Btw the reason I want to do this is because I'm getting an error of `Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.` So I'm guessing this is a permission issue because I did not link my existing sendgrid to my azure sendgrid account. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This page explains well. How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

We are using existing sendgrid account in azure function and using function binding.  There was no linking required, existing account also provides APIKEY, that is all that is needed. Example here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp

Comment: I followed the instruction, after I created a sendgrid account in Azure I don't know what to do next. How do I linked my existing to the newly created send grid account?

Comment: My point was, you can use existing account without creating azure sendgrid account. Find the APIKEY from existing account and use it in the program you create.

Comment: I have the APIKEY that I generated from Sendgrid. But using this key and the username I can't send the email and it seems that the sending of email is blocked somehow in Azure? Or do I need to do something to allow the sending of sendgrid account?

Comment: I guess your issue may have been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737062/3684818