# Convert type string to Secure String

Tags: powershell, sendgrid, azure-powershell

I have prepared the PowerShell script for sending emails using SendGrid. But while converting plain text password of SendGrid account into secure string, then I am getting the following error:

> “unable to convert type string to secure string”

Sample Script:

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Demo123" -AsPlainText -Force
```

So, can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where did you run the command?

Comment: `$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Demo123" -AsPlainText -Force` is probably not the line where the error occurred. Please show what you are actually doing and include the line in the question where the “*unable to convert type string to secure string*” does occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Username ="Name@azure.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Demo123" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password
$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
$EmailFrom = "from@mail.com"
$EmailTo = "to@mail.com"
$Subject = "SendGrid test"
$Body = "SendGrid testing successful"

Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $credential -Usessl -Port 587 -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -Body $Body
```

Comment: Thanks @Iron, Now I'm getting this error `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.`

Comment: Did you check this [SmtpException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20252948/1701026) answer? If that does help, I recommend you to open a new question.

Comment: I have checked the above link already but that is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run same command in Powershell:

[image]

My Powershell Version is `5.7.0.18831`.

Comment: I run the same command in local PowerShell, then it is working. But whenever I'm executing it from Azure  DevOps release pipeline, then I'm getting the error.

Comment: Specify the powershell version in azure devops and try once.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: No @singhh-msft, The issue is, I have used  `securestring` type instead of `string' type for the password parameter. In the release task, I'm trying to override the parameter values by reading it from variables section. There I'm getting the above error, but now it resolved.

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. But, you mentioned something else in your question. You should use correct dataType for any variable.