# How to resolve Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed error while sending email using SMTPClient

Tags: c#, office365, smtpclient

We have an email accounts as **emailName@companyDomain.in** and this is configured in **Office365**. We want to send an email using **emailName@companyDomain.in** from C#.
Below code sometimes work and sometimes not (most of the times not working). Giving Error as *"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed"*. Code is

```
 public static void SendEmail(string toEmailId, string subject, string mailMessage)
    {
        string fromEmail = "emailName@companyDomain.in";
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(toEmailId);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail, "Sender Name");
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = mailMessage;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // Tried by commenting this too
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmail, "password");
        client.Port = 587; // Tried port number 25
        client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

Can you please give any hint about what could be wrong?

Comment: Does it work every time if you use same parameters (email account, TO, message) and Machine running c# code?  Check send box to make sure limits are not exceeded.  Some servers if messages are not sent will only allow a max number before failing.

Comment: It fails for the same parameters, running on my local. Daily limit not reached too, just confirmed that.

Comment: What is different between working and not working?

Comment: Working means sending email and not working means throwing an above exception.

Comment: Check if you are using the correct target name for a TLS secure email with you ADMIN.  Most people having this issue the problem goes away what they change the target.  You may be using a target that is overloaded or is designed for non secure and does not work every time with a secure email.

Comment: How long does it take for error to occur.  If it is 30 seconds that means you never connected to the proxy server.  The email credentials have to be verified by a proxy server on your network that is used for port 587 before being sent.  When the proxy doesn't respond in 30 seconds your SMTP times out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding this code before creating the smtp client worked for me.

```
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

Comment: after loooong time I found this line of code resolved my issue.

Comment: thank you so much! it resolved my issue where i randomly got a net_io_connectoinclosed error.

Comment: It worked for me too!
I don't understand why, but it works

Comment: Its working without no issues now. Many thanks for the lead.

Comment: Worked for me using only SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 0):

First Use Port = 587

Generally STARTTLS is required to send mail, Adding the Security Protocol Tls12 will help to resolve this issue.

Secondly test the stmp connection using powershell

```
$userName = 'username_here'
$password = 'xxxxxxxxx'
$pwdSecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText $password
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $pwdSecureString

$sendMailParams = @{
    From = 'abc.com'
    To = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    Subject = 'Test SMTP'
    Body = 'Test SMTP'
    SMTPServer = 'smtp.server.com'
    Port = 587
    UseSsl = $true
    Credential = $credential
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailParams
```

Thirdly If this send out the email, Add below code inside SmtpClient function:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                      | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```