# Authenticate to Gmail smtp using Xoauth2. Results in Username and Password not accepted

Tags: c#, oauth, smtp, gmail, mailkit

Due to the recent removal of [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) and not wanting to go along the route of an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).   I have been trying to enable [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) with the smtp server as a more secure sustainable method of authorization for my users.

I have created a simple console appication to test this.

1. Uses mailkit
2. connects to googles smtp server
3. uses xoauth2.
4. Created installed application on google cloud console.

Authorization appears to work i am getting an access token back.  The issue seams to be that the smtp server will not accept it, or possibly how I am applying it.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;


var path = @"C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json";
var scopes = new[] { "email" };
var userName = "test2";

var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(path).Secrets,
    scopes,
    userName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), true)).Result;

credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();

var message = new EmailMessage()
{
    From = "xxx@gmail.com",
    To = "xxx@gmail.com",
    MessageText = "test",
    Subject = "test"
};

try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
        
        var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 ("xxx@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);
        await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2, CancellationToken.None);
        
        client.Send(message.GetMessage());
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int i = 1;  // throws MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException here
}


public class EmailMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }

    public MimeMessage GetMessage()
    {
        var body = MessageText;
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("test", From));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("test", To));
        message.Subject = Subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = body };
        return message;
    }
}
```

The full error message is as follows.

> MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 535: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
> 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials da26-20020a056402177a00b004315050d7dfsm6610655edb.81 - gsmtp
> at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(SaslMechanism mechanism, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\YouTube\dev\Gmail\Code\SMTPTesting\SmtpTest\SmtpTestXoauth2\Program.cs:line 38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that after struggling with this for a while.

The standard email scope was incorrect.  XOauth2 with the smtp server has two scopes only used for it

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.imap_admin

the last one apparently only works for workspace.

## fix

The only thing i needed to change in the code was

```
var scopes = new[] { "email" };
```

to

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" };
```

More info can be found here [Oauth2 scopes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol#oauth_20_scopes)