# How to send SSIS failure notification when executing from SQL Agent Job

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL Agent Job with steps that resemble the following:

1. Exec SSIS package A
2. Exec SSIS package B
3. Exec SSIS package C
4. Exec stored proc

I have it set up so that if any of the SSIS packages fail, the job moves on to next step. The package failure notification comes from SSIS. I have 2 script tasks. One in event handler to capture/append error codes/messages to a variable:
[image]
[image]

The second script task is in control flow and grabs the appended error message variables and  other email forming variables and sends them to an outlook email account:
[image]
[image]

This works when running the package with my credentials + just the individual package. When I try to run the package through the SQL Agent Job with default credentials (or even my own) I get the following errors:
[image]

The desired result is SQL Agent Job runs completely regardless of any of steps 1-3 failing. When any step 1-3 fail, within SSIS the failure email message is sent.

EDIT: SQL Agent Job
[image]

We are using the legacy Package Deployment Model. The Package lives on the file system.

Comment: The error message is curious. When you say you're running it from Agent, could you post the job step definition for us? Also, when you're running the package in VS, what is the project and package protection level?

Comment: @billinkc Not too sure what you mean by step definition, but I created an edit and attached a picture of the step properties. Also the protection level is defaulted to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey

Comment: Normally, one would right click on the job and select Script to new Window or something along those lines but the Screenshot will suffice in this case.