# Sending Email that requires secure connection

Tags: c#

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    string to = "dattatray96@gmail.com";
    mail.To.Add(to);
    mail.From = new MailAddress("dattatray96@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Mail";
    mail.Body = " HI";

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Try to use 2step varification form gmail setting and generate new password for your application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: This is also right http://stackoverflow.com/a/9572958/3180471 This is perfect solution this works for me.

Comment: Lucky you have two factor verification on that account ;) You might want to consider editing your question and removing your password.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

You first need to enable sending emails from your gmail account by following [these](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en#ts=1665119) steps

---

For SSL enabled gmail, you need to use the port:

```
465
```

Reference:

[email.about.com](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm)

Comment: see here 5.5.1 authnatication error  so no need to change port number

Comment: @Vap, check this out:   [StachOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227532/gmail-530-5-5-1-authentication-required-learn-more-at   check this

Comment: @Vap, I think its neither my suggestion nor yours were wrong, both the answers are correct. see my updated answer for details