# Can't send mail from MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, system.net.mail

I'm trying to send an email through MVC. I specifically say MVC because the same code (which is pretty generic to `Net.Mail`) works in a windows forms application and not in MVC.

I googled around and tried various settings, with no luck. I think this might be a problem with MVC or some platform I'm using.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPort"]);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]);
smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailHost"];
smtp.Timeout = (20 * 1000);

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"]);
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(item.Recipient));
mail.Subject = item.Subject;
mail.Body = item.Body;

smtp.Send(mail);
```

All I need is a way of sending mails from MVC

Update:
Error I'm getting:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.Flush() at
>   System.Net.Mail.ReadLinesCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn) at
>   System.Net.Mail.EHelloCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String domain)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

[Update]
My findings:

```
Platform    Port    SSL Result
MVC         587 true    Error
MVC         587 false   got mail
MVC         465 true    Time out
MVC         465 false   Time out

WinForm     587 true    got mail
WinForm     587 false   got mail
WinForm     465 true    Time out
WinForm     465 false   Time out
```

On Thunder bird I'm using port 587 with STARTTLS.

Any ideas

Comment: "Can't send mail from MVC" does not describe the problem. It's very unlikely to be failing silently, so either you're catching and throwing away the error, the code is never being run, or the SMTP server isn't sending the e-mail onwards for some reason.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? you have not described the exact nature of problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Apologies, updated accordingly.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420788/5947043) is a good general description of the possible causes of your error message (I just googled the error, it's easy to find). So the first things I'd do would be to check that the mailserver is definitely running, check you're using the right port, and check there are no firewalls blocking your route.

Comment: If you're using Google, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250322/sending-email-asp-net-c-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remot)

Comment: @ADyson I'll go through it, but it's not the server. As mentioned the exact same code works in a windows forms application with no issue at all.

Comment: @John Not google. It's my own domain.

Comment: And do `mailHost` and `mailPort` have the _exact_ same values as the WinForms app?

Comment: @John Exactly! That's the curve ball I'm getting. Perhaps ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""] changes the values slightly?

Comment: Are you running this code on the same machine as the windows forms app? If not, then look for differences e.g. firewalls, available network routes, rules on the mailserver about allowed IPs, that sort of thing.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""] will not alter any values, no, they are just strings. MVC uses it the exact same way as a Forms app would

Comment: Try sending the mail using gmail, if it works, you will know that the code works and there is something related to your domain settings.

Comment: Can you `smtp.EnableSsl = false;` to rule out SSL/TLS issues.

Comment: @Adyson Same machine in my dev environment

Comment: have you checked the the winforms app is currently working and sending mail from your dev machine? If the code is genuinely identical, the settings are genuinely identical, the machine is identical, but the socket connection cannot be made then it _sounds_ like an environment problem, possibly external to your machine (e.g. temporary outage or something). The only other local issue I could thing of might be windows firewall on the machine - does it have rules about which specific applications can make outbound connections, perhaps?

Comment: @phuzi Thank you for the suggestion. I actually rolled my eyes when I saw it but did it out of frustration and it worked. I suppose it's a solution, but I want SSL. Perhaps someone can help making sense of this? More to follow, just give me a sec while I investigate.

Comment: Hmm, are you using SSL in the WinForms version? Obviously the mailserver needs to support SSL connections.

Comment: Could you confirm what version of .Net/ASP.Net you are using (Core/Framework with version number). There are some differences in support out of the box with SSL/TLS versions.