# Laravel 5.3 . Sending email on registration

Tags: php, laravel-5

When this error occurs?

> Expected response code `250` but got code `530`, with message `530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError ux6sm1270700wjb.18 - gsmtp`

I tried google but unable to solve. I am using `Laravel 5.3` and sending a email on registration of user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227532/gmail-530-5-5-1-authentication-required-learn-more-at)

Comment: Show your code and what you tried, as no one can guess it.