# Password reset email getting 530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

When I try to send a password reset email, I get the following error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. I've looked at Stack Overflow and Laracasts and found similar problems. I've tried two different email addresses and servers. But I'm getting the same error.

Here's my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=[password]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Here is my mail.php file:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),
'from' => [
   'address' => 'xx@gmail.com',
   'name' => 'XX',
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Any ideas what I've got wrong here?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227532/gmail-530-5-5-1-authentication-required-learn-more-at

Comment: did you check your creds in bootstrap/cache/config.php ?

Comment: There's no config.php in my bootstrap/cache folder.

Comment: @ceejayoz - It's not duplicate because it's not a problem with gmail. It's a problem with sending mail. I'm using Gmail but as I said at the beginning of my post, I've tried 2 different email addresses and servers.

Comment: @jerauf And you get an "530 authentication required" from the non-Gmail mail server, as well? What's the second mail provider you're attempting with?

Comment: Yes. It's Media Temple's.

Answer (score 26):

I found that changing the .env file requires you to clear you config cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This worked and now email is sending.

Comment: you are savour for me bro!! wish I could accept your answer

Comment: upvoted! I'm a fool trying php artisan clear:cache. It's CONFIG:CACHE!